# Use PowerShell to parse IBM MQ report to format Prometheus can use

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq, prometheus

I am doing a POC for Prometheus and one of the things we would like to get metrics from is an IBM MQ server running on W2012R2. There is a Prometheus exporter for IBM MQ but that is for Linux and isn't working on Windows.

We do have an option to schedule a report to write data to a file, however the output for that file is useless for Prometheus, so the document has te be reformatted.

I've been breaking my head on how to achieve this using PowerShell but since I lack scripting experience with PowerShell I decided to ask here for help.

You guys have any idea how to change a report in this layout:

```
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2015.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QMGR.


     1 : DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*) 

AMQ8450: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1)               CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   CONNAME(10.10.10.10)                    CURRENT
   RQMNAME(QMGR)                           STATUS(RUNNING)
   SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)                    
AMQ8450: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3)               CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   CONNAME(10.10.10.10)                    CURRENT
   STATUS(RUNNING)                         SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
```

To something looking like this:

```
status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"} running
substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"} receive
status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10"} running
substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10"} receive
```

This is what I came up with so far, not exactly pretty I guess but it seems to be a step in the right direction...

```
$Contents = Get-Content ".\CHSTATUS.txt" | select -Skip 5 
foreach($Line in $Contents) {
    foreach($channel in [Regex]::Matches($Line, '(?<=CHANNEL\()(.*?)(?=\))')) {}
    foreach($chltype in [Regex]::Matches($Line, '(?<=CHLTYPE\()(.*?)(?=\))')) {}
    foreach($conname in [Regex]::Matches($Line, '(?<=CONNAME\()(.*?)(?=\))')) {}
    foreach($status in [Regex]::Matches($Line, '(?<=STATUS\()(.*?)(?=\))')) {}
    foreach($substate in [Regex]::Matches($Line, '(?<=SUBSTATE\()(.*?)(?=\))')) {
    Write-Host "status{channel=""$channel"", chltype=""$chltype"", conname=""$conname""}" $status 
    Write-Host "substate{channel=""$channel"", chltype=""$chltype"", conname=""$conname""}" $substate
    }
}
```

Hope somebody here can give me a push in the right direction on how to tackle this.

Comment: What version of IBM MQ do you have installed?

Comment: There should be no reason why you can't use the Prometheus exporter at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-metric-samples provided you follow the compilation instructions and have a suitable startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert that input and parse out the fields, you can do this:

```
$inputFile = 'D:\Report.txt'

# read the file, split into usable blocks and collect in variable $report
$report = ((Get-Content -Path $inputFile -Raw) -split '.*Display Channel Status details\.' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    $channel  = ([regex] 'CHANNEL\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
    $chltype  = ([regex] 'CHLTYPE\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value.ToLower()
    $conname  = ([regex] 'CONNAME\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
    $rqmname  = ([regex] 'RQMNAME\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
    $status   = ([regex] 'STATUS\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value.ToLower()
    $substate = ([regex] 'SUBSTATE\(([^)]+)\)').Match($_).Groups[1].Value.ToLower()

    if ($rqmname) {
        $out = 'status{{channel="{0}", chltype="{1}", conname="{2}", rqmname="{3}"}} {4}' + "`r`n" +
               'substate{{channel="{0}", chltype="{1}", conname="{2}", rqmname="{3}"}} {5}'
        # output the two lines including rqmname
        $out -f $channel, $chltype, $conname, $rqmname, $status, $substate

    }
    else {
        $out = 'status{{channel="{0}", chltype="{1}", conname="{2}"}} {3}' + "`r`n" +
               'substate{{channel="{0}", chltype="{1}", conname="{2}"}} {4}'
        # output the two lines excluding rqmname
        $out -f $channel, $chltype, $conname, $status, $substate
    }
}) -join "`r`n"

# output on screen
$report

# or save to new file
$report | Set-Content -Path 'D:\ConvertedReport.txt'
```

Result:

> ```
> status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"} running
> substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"} receive
> status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10"} running
> substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="rcvr", conname="10.10.10.10"} receive
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a good approach.  It would be far simpler to use Java/PCF and output the data in the format that you want.

I published a simple (fully functioning) MQ/PCF/Java program called: [MQListChannelStatus01](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=5230).

Just update the parameters to be:

```
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_ATTRS,
                     new int []
                     {
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_SUBSTATE,
                        CMQC.MQCA_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME
                     } );
```

The thing you need to be aware of is that you will get information for ALL channels that are running, attempting to run, etc..  Hence, "MQCA_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME" is not valid for all channel types.

You will need to do the following in the "for loop":

```
int chlType = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_TYPE);

String remoteQMName ="";
if (chlType == CMQXC.MQCHT_RECEIVER)
{
   remoteQMName = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQC.MQCA_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME);
   if (remoteQMName != null)
      remoteQMName = remoteQMName.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar in the past for a Nagios alert for MQ channel status. Here's a general purpose function for parsing the output into structured hashtables:

```bsh
function Invoke-ParseMqscOutput
{
    param( $output )

    # strip off the main header and split the AMQ#### records into a $parts array
    $recordHeaderPattern = "^(?<AmqCode>AMQ\d+): (?<AmqDescription>.*)$";
    $parts = [regex]::Split($stdout, $recordHeaderPattern, "Multiline");

    # patterns for splitting attribute strings into AttributeName and AttributeValues
    #     + e.g. CHANNEL(QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1)
    # as well as some pathological cases like:
    #     + special characters        - e.g. ATTRXNAME(attrx.ATTRX_12345[W X-Y\Z])
    #     + comma-separated lists     - e.g. ATTRYNAME(ATTRY1, ATTRY2)
    #     + "flags" with no "( ... )" - e.g. CURRENT
    $attributeNamePattern = "(?<AttributeName>[a-z|A-Z]+)";
    $attributeValuesPattern = "(?<AttributeValues>[a-z|A-Z|0-9|,|_|\-|\.|\[|\]|\\|\s]*)";
    $attributePattern = $attributeNamePattern + "(\(" + $attributeValuesPattern + "\))?";

    # convert the parts array into an array of hashtables
    # (one hashtable per record in the output)
    $records = @();
    $index = 1;
    while( $index -lt $parts.Length )
    {

        # split the attributes block into individual attributes and parse them
        $attributes = [ordered] @{};
        $attributeMatches = [regex]::Matches($parts[$index + 2], $attributePattern, "Multiline");
        $attributeMatches | % {
            $attributeName = $_.Groups["AttributeName"].Value;
            $attributeValues = $_.Groups["AttributeValues"].Value;
            $attributeValues = $attributeValues.Split(",") | % { $_.Trim(); };
            $attributes.Add($attributeName, $attributeValues);
        }

        # collect the next 3 "$parts" values into a single record
        $records += @{
            "AmqCode" = $parts[$index]
            "Message" = $parts[$index + 1]
            "Attributes" = $attributes
        };

        # move on to the start of the next record
        $index = $index + 3;

    }

    return @(, $records );

}
```

example 
usage:

```bsh
$output = @"
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2015.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QMGR.


     1 : DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*)

AMQ8450: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1)               CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   CONNAME(10.10.10.10)                    CURRENT
   RQMNAME(QMGR)                           STATUS(RUNNING)
   SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
   ATTRXNAME(attrx.ATTRX_12345[W X-Y\Z])
   ATTRYNAME(ATTRY1, ATTRY2)
AMQ8450: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3)               CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   CONNAME(10.10.10.10)                    CURRENT
   STATUS(RUNNING)                         SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
"@

$records = Invoke-ParseMqscOutput $output;

# examples of how to traverse the $records:
write-host $records[0].Attributes.CHANNEL      # QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1
write-host $records[0].Attributes.ATTRXNAME    # attrx.ATTRX_12345[W X-Y\Z]
write-host $records[0].Attributes.ATTRYNAME[0] # ATTRY1
```

And then to generate your output you can do this:

```bsh
$metrics = @();
foreach( $record in $records )
{
    switch( $record.AmqCode )
    {
        "AMQ8450" {
            $attributes = $record.Attributes;
            $metrics += "status{channel=`"$($attributes.CHANNEL)`", chltype=`"$($attributes.CHLTYPE)`", conname=`"$($attributes.CONNAME)`", rqmname=`"$($attributes.RQMNAME)`"} $($attributes.STATE)";
            $metrics += "substate{channel=`"$($attributes.CHANNEL)`", chltype=`"$($attributes.CHLTYPE)`", conname=`"$($attributes.CONNAME)`", rqmname=`"$($attributes.RQMNAME)`"} $($attributes.SUBSTATE)";
        }
    }
}

write-host ($metrics | fl * | out-string);
```

which outputs:

```
status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="RCVR", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"}
substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R1", chltype="RCVR", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname="QMGR"} RECEIVE
status{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="RCVR", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname=""}
substate{channel="QMGR.HOSTNAME.R3", chltype="RCVR", conname="10.10.10.10", rqmname=""} RECEIVE
```

Note that if you're **able** to use the Websphere API to invoke the commands you'll have a much easier time processing the results, but if you absolutely **have** to parse the output from `runmqsc.exe` then the above might help you...